# What is the stalk of the structure sheaf of the plane?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{C}$. How do I compute the local ring corresponding to the stalk of $\mathcal{O}$ of the point $(0,0)$? I tried computing the localization of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ by the prime ideal $(x,y)$ which gives the ring
$$
\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x,y)} = \left\{ \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} : g(0,0) \neq 0 \right\}
$$
But I'm not sure if there is a more explicit presentation of this ring

Comment: @Kamina in the examples of page 8 of http://www.mccme.ru/~valya/Notes.pdf, she claims this should be $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$, but I don't see why this is true.

Comment: Kamina is wrong and so are those notes; that's the completion of the local ring at its maximal ideal. (There are a lot more meromorphic functions than this.) Your computation is correct.